# 18.04 not waking up from suspend

Tags: 18.04, suspend

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-23-generic

$ lsb_release -r
Release:    18.04
```

First happened after upgrading kernel version to `4.15.0-23-generic` but when I switched back to `4.15.0-20-generic` it worked fine until now (there was an update a few days ago). Now my laptop does not wake up from suspend on either kernel version.

Any suggestions on what to look at / try out? I've tried the suggestions I've been able to find online but to no avail.

Comment: Thanks @pHeLiOn, the accepted answer worked for me, and now the laptop is waking up even on the `4.15.0-23-generic` kernel version.

Comment: I can hardly believe my eyes: the issue ("Ubuntu 18.04 - Dell XPS13 9370 no longer suspends on lid close ") which was given by the moderators as the duplicate of this is completely different from this.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was solved after updating to kernel 4.18 with ukuu
Ukuu is a program that allows the easy installation and removal of newer or older kernel versions in a graphical way It is easy to use and install: [makeuseof.com/tag/upgrade-kernel-ukuu-ubuntu](http://makeuseof.com/tag/upgrade-kernel-ukuu-ubuntu). Of course , you can use command line or download the kernel and install I didn't have any problem with the new kernel but in case you face  problems, you can uninstall it by booting from the old one, using the grub menu
Hope it helps

Comment: @Fabby: Hi. Ukuu is a program that allows the easy installation and removal of newer or older kernel versions in a graphical way It is easy to use and install: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrade-kernel-ukuu-ubuntu/.   Of course , you can use command line or download the kernel as a .deb file and install it. About disadvantages, I don't thing there are any serious ones since, in case you face such problems, you can uninstall the offending kernel. Even in the case the system doesn't boot, you can just boot from the older (and working kernel) from grub menu

Comment: I'm one of the reviewers here on the site and I know, but the OP might not, so giving you a chance to [edit] your answer so it becomes clearer. Please read [How do I write a good answer](/help/how-to-answer) and then please [edit] your answer and improve it. **;-)**